# Testing issue with Tkinter event

Tags: python, tkinter, nose, python-unittest

I'm writing unit tests for a tkinter widget that is part of a larger application.
I have some issue related to event triggering on labels in order to assert callback execution.

Please note that my test code works well when checking buttons' callbacks. In such cases I write something similar to:

```
    a_button = self.sc._inner_frame.winfo_children()[2].winfo_children()[2]
    a_button.invoke()
    self.assertTrue(self.controller.add_sell_indicator.called)
```

and it works.

For labels, however, there is not an `invoke()` method, so I'm using `event_generate()` as per:

```
    label = self.sc._inner_frame.winfo_children()[0].winfo_children()[0]
    label.event_generate("<Button-1>")
    self.assertTrue(self.controller.get_selected_indicator.called)
```

but the test fails because the event `<Button-1>` is not triggered.

I played a bit moving alternatively an `ipdb.set_trace()` before and after `label.event_generate`. I noticed that only when I put it before the call and then press `c` to continue with execution, *without firing any other command in the interpreter shell*, the test doesn't fail.

Any hints or workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use the `warp` option to cause the mouse to be over the widget. It could very well be that the widget has a check to ignore button events if the cursor isn't over the widget. You might be able to get away with generating a `<Enter>` event before the click.

I recall having to do these tricks when I was writing testing software in tcl/tk, but I've never done it with Tkinter. I don't even know if the `warp` option is supported in Tkinter.  You might have to write your own wrapper around the core tcl/tk event generate command.

Comment: thx for suggesting. warp option exists but doesn't do the trick. Besides, when I put a set_trace, I actually did not add anything else to `label.event_generate("<Button-1>")`, but the event is not triggered.

Comment: When the debugger pauses execution, are you moving the mouse at all, in order to interact with the debugger?

Comment: It doesn't affect the result. Either I click on the shell window or press Alt+Tab, when I resume execution the test pass

Comment: My fault. In order to avoid [this bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue20567) I was suppressing `update_idletasks()` with a fake MagicMock in the test setUp. Apparently, this affects the event flow, though it doesn't mess with button.invoke() that still worked fine. Out of curiosity, the bug shows up only when I run nosetests without specifying any path, but this is another matter.